# Dedicate one whole day for abs

Tags: workout-routines, abdominals

I work out three days a week, two times per day (very early and very late in the day), just because I like it (I don't have a massive body, but literally working out makes me feel good so I go there as often as I can)

I do abs exercise (not many though) at the the end of each my work out session.

Though I generally like my body, the abs part is not exactly what I'd like to see, I'm still in shape I'd say, but yet I don't like that part.

I was thinking whether or not it would make sense adding one work out session where I focus only on abs, but still carrying on with my current routine for the other days, including abs.

The question is whether or not there a benefit in having a further workout day fully dedicated to abs (in addition and not substitution to the other days where I do abs at the end of the workout)?

Comment: Can you edit your question to address what it is you're hoping to accomplish by adding another day?

Comment: @rrirower done, it should be clearer I hope.

Comment: There may very well be a benefit to adding another day.  However, you still haven't indicated what type of benefit you're looking for.  Is it to lose adipose?  Or, build bigger abs?  Both?  We can't answer if you don't indicate what you're desired end result is.

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36704/at-what-point-is-it-worth-using-a-powerlifting-belt/36715#36715

Answer (score 3):

Your abs are no different than the rest of your musculature, especially if you compare them to something like your [erector spinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erector_spinae_muscles): they keep you upright, erect, and for big exertions you will engage them [isometrically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_exercise). Human abdominal muscles are generally (and obviously) made up of [type 1 "slow twitch" fibers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/161688) which favor endurance over power output.

Regardless of how much you want to lift, you shouldn't be lifting twice a day unless you have a *very* good training program. [It takes time for your muscles to recover](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19322/7091) from the damage you do while lifting.

Given the nature of your abdominals (assistance to keep you upright), the slow twitch muscle fibers, and that for heavy loads they are engaged isometrically, I think you can start to see the picture of why they're trained they way they are. Properly performed deadlifts, squats, and overhead presses will work your abs in addition to whatever direct abominal work you're doing.

My advice:

- You're probably lifting too often, [it takes time for muscles to recover](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19322/7091) regardless of how hard you want to push.
- If you have [a good strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091), you'll have plenty of ab work built in.
- Abs are made in the kitchen, as they say. The picture below is fairly accurate and demonstrates that visible abs are almost entirely dictated by body fat.

[image]