# Time per workouts using ab wheel for bigger abs workout

Tags: workout-routines, abdominals

What are the workouts that will give me results using only an ab wheel.

How much time should it be good to make them huge? I can do all day, I eat healthily but what I want is really to focus only to make it big. I have heard weights are good, but using I think ab wheel too it will help me.

As a result how long should I workout a day my abs with the ab wheel.

Comment: Make what huge? Your abs? Good luck with that. Also note that a 6pack tends to look stupid to most people if the rest of your body isn't muscular but just skinny. You need to balance that a bit. As for your question, have you tried Googling 'ab wheel workout'?

Comment: i have done already what you have wrote.I workout my whole body but i didn't want to mention this because i ask something specific.Ofcourse my abs.It may here have more advance workouts i thought for make them huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several q&a's on here about abs, [you should maybe check out this one](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/36879/7091).

Abdominal muscles "get huge" when the fat around them is removed. The "hugeness" is the contrast, the muscles themselves don't really get much bigger.

[Abdominal muscles are primarily made up of type 1 "slow twitch" fibers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/161688): the human body has (rightly) designed these muscles to do the same boring job every day, all day, similar to your tongue and heart. It's not designed to exert power, push heavy rocks, or other strength goals: your abs are there to keep your erect, help you breathe (especially as a little kid and when in distress) and protect your organs. All of that is about slow twitch.

You should follow [a proper strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) which will include compound lifts that will require your abdominal muscles to do their stabilizing job with increasing resistance. [A proper strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) will also include accessory exercises, like ab-wheels or incline sit ups. You will not outsmart a good training program.